# CK Editor 4.5.3 how to remove the About button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Link to CK EDITOR: http://ckeditor.com/demo#widgets

How do i remove the "?" Button. On clicking on it, It shows About CK Editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the toolbar elements to show through the config. Check the documentation: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_toolbar.

Also, you can just remove the button using `config.removeButtons = 'About';`. Look at http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-removeButtons.